# Which animal names have grammatical gender, and which have common gender?

Tags: gender, animals

In [Allen & Greenough, §34](https://books.google.com/books?id=Q7cAAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA15), I see a short discussion on the gender of animal names:

> Many nouns may be either masculine or feminine, according to the sex of the object.  These are said to be of Common Gender: as, **exsul**, *exile;* **bōs**, *ox* or *cow;* **parēns**, *parent*.
>   Note.—Several names of animals have a grammatical gender, independent of sex.  These are called *epicene*.  Thus lepus, *hare*, is always masculine, and vulpēs, *fox*, is always feminine.

My question is, are there any clues as to *which* animals have "common gender," and which have a fixed grammatical gender?  A few ideas:

- If it's easy to tell the gender of an animal just by looking at it, then it's common gender, otherwise it's grammatical.

  - An issue with this is that *canis* appears to be common gender, while *vulpes* is grammatical – and it's surely not much more difficult to identify gender in a fox than in a dog.
- If it's a domestic animal, then it's common gender, otherwise it's grammatical.

  - But while *canis* and *bos* are common gender, *ovis* is feminine.

Is this simply a matter of memorization?  Or is there a guideline, if not a rule, for animal name gender?

Comment: Very interesting question, I guess I've just never thought about it as systematically as you have. It's also interesting how the Germanic system works for comparison: a cow is always feminine and a bull always masculine, but a dog can be either. But then there is bitch...

Comment: Luraghi 2013 observes that "[n]ouns that refer to non-breeding animals often do not have variable gender: hēkhelidṓn ‘the swallow (fem.)’ usually also refers to the male, in spite of some sporadic masculine forms; ho bátrakhos ‘the frog (masc.)’, with no sex-specific reference." **She did say this about Greek but we can apply this to Latin too.** To use her terminology, non-breeding animals often have a fixed grammatical gender.

Answer (score 7):

In Latin (and Romance languages) grammatical gender usually corresponds to real gender only with animals which are very near to human life, that is animals we *need* to distinguish by gender. Obviously this applies to humans too.

So we have *parens*, but also *mater* and *pater*. But we have only *exsul*, probably because back then most of the time political exile was inflicted to males.

As for other animals, we don't usually care about the sex of a *hare* or a *fox*; the really few times we do, we can just say "female fox": no need for a new word here; *ovis* is feminine, while *aries* and *vervex* are male, because sheep were of utmost importance for the Romans, so they often needed to distinguish between male and female. So *bos* is neutral, but *vacca* is used for the female and *taurus* for the male. There is also *hircus* and *caper* vs *capra* and *capella* for male vs female goats (thanks @TKR).

As for *canis*, they would call the female *canis femina*: this is probably because the sex of a dog was of little importance at the beginning: maybe only to dog breeders, who maybe had a custom word that just happened to not survive. We have instead *catula* and *catulus*; this is probably because the diminutive form is also used to express attachment, not only real physical smallness: and if you are attached to a dog, you'll use its correct gender if you can (see italian *cagnolina*); while a female form of "canis" was difficult to create, the female form of "catulus" was immediately available.

Anyway, there is no way to be sure about every single animal; you can make a good guess, but you should always check on your dictionary. For example it's not a given that a generic word *bos* must exist – it doesn't for sheep (maybe because there weren't "standard" situations when males and females needed to be named together).