# What would "opossum" be in Latin?

Tags: vocabulary, english-to-latin-translation, contemporary-latin

I was wondering how one would translate the word "opossum" into Latin.

It derives from Native American names for opossum meaning variably "white dog" and "white animal," so it could be translated literally into Latin. Of course, the word "opossum" itself could just be kept, and take the construction of a 2nd declension neuter noun.

Mostly just want to field some opinions. Thanks!

Comment: Actually all animals have official zoological names, in this case Didelphis virginiana.

Comment: Are you looking for something like a word that a Roman would have used for the animal? [Scientific and Latin names are two different things](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/371/79), and it could be worth clarifying what you're after. Good colloquial alternatives to a scientific name is an interesting thing to think about.

Comment: I always thought that the plural of *opossum* should be *opossumus*.

Answer (score 6):

If you are looking for something to call these animals colloquially, I would go with the simple neuter *opossum*.
No other name will be easy to understand, and I value functional communication above sticking with classical words.
To in no way help me drive home this argument, here is a hendecasyllabic verse:

> O, possum hoc animal vocare opossum.
>   Oh, I can call this animal an opossum.

[The scientific name is not the same as a Latin name](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/371/79), and just like nobody would call a dog *canis lupus* in daily life, neither would anyone call an opossum *Didelphis virginiana* (the only species in the US) or *didelphida* (the name of the family is *Didelphidae*).

Because opossums are small compared to dogs, I would modify the name "white dog" to "little white dog", *canicula alba*.
That's pretty heavy for repeated use, so after introduction you could go with *canicula*.
But if there is any risk of confusion, the word *opossum* is the safest bet, albeit not previously a Latin word to my knowledge.

Comment: It's rare to borrow a noun from a completely different language family that just happens to fit a standard native form for nouns. I say we take it as-is! _opossum, opossī_ (n.) But wait…neuter gender for an animal? Don't all animals in Latin have masculine, feminine, or common gender—never neuter? ([This question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/1410/118) doesn't quite answer.) A quick search finds non-neuter gender even in _mūlus, mūla,_ and _hinnus._

Comment: Oh no, another decision: _opossum, ōpossum, opōssum,_ or _ōpōssum?_ What precedents relate to this?

Comment: @BenKovitz There's the word *animal* itself, but I can't think of other neuter animal names. Nevertheless, the word *opossum* is so convenient that it practically forces neuter; changing to *opossus* or something feels forced. Vowel quantities can be decided based on other languages as Latin doesn't restrict it. I thought of both Os as short as they are in all languages I know. (My scansion breaks down if the first one is long!)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a single completely obvious choice, so this is just my thoughts on some possibilities. The order here is just to make this answer less similar to the existing answers.

### "Sariga" (or similar: *sarigua, sairguea*)

I wouldn't go so far as recommending it, but I wanted to mention that another stem used in a few Romance languages' words for *opossum* is *sarig-,* as in French *[sarigue](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sarigue)* and Italian *[sariga](https://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_inglese/Italiano/S/sariga.shtml).* (But *opossum* is also used, and appears to be more common than *sariga* in Italian.)

The etymology is said to be from Tupi, but the details of what the original Tupi form sounded like and meant are fairly unclear to me. Some Romance forms have [w] (Spanish *zarigüeya*). Possible Latinized forms could be *sarīga, sarīgua, sarīguēa.* (I'd go with long ī since the Italian word seems to have penultimate stress.)

*Sarigua* seems to have had some use as an alternative scientific name at one point ([A PRELIMINARY STUDY OF THE NORTH AMERICAN OPOSSUMS OF THE GENUS DIDELPHIS](http://digitallibrary.amnh.org/bitstream/handle/2246/499/v2/dspace/ingest/pdfSource/bul/B014a11.pdf?sequence=1), page 163).

The one advantage I can see is that *sarīga* or similar would make for a fairly normal-looking feminine noun of the first declension, like *formīca, formīcae* "ant" or *aquila, aquilae* "eagle".

A couple of major disadvantages:

- Little if any use in Latin.

  I found 1 citation of the form "sariguea":

  > Est memorabile animal Sariguea in nouo orbe, et in India Orientali adinuentum: est catti, seu felis magnitudine; posteriores, ac priores pedes pellicula interposita coniunguntur, velut anseribus in pedibus est pellis, aut qualis est vespertilionibus ...

  ([Dies Caniculares, Hoc est Colloquia tria et viginti physica, etc](https://books.google.com/books?id=U_ym8M_EJYUC&pg=PA161&lpg=PA161&dq=%22Sariguea%22))
- It's probably recognizable to much fewer people than *opossum.*

### Opossum

The recognizability is the big attraction of this choice, I think.

As Ben Kovitz mentioned in a comment, it is fairly odd for the name of an animal to belong to the neuter gender in Latin. But as a nominative singular form, *opossum* is really not compatible with any Latin declension pattern other than second-declension neuter.

"Opossum" is invariable for number in Italian, so treating it as invariable for case and number could be another option to consider. I have the impression that many modern Latin enthusiasts try whenever possible to avoid loaning names as invariable nouns, but it isn't an unheard of strategy historically.

### Didelphis (or "didelphys"?)

While not as likely I think as *opossum* to be immediately recognizable, *didelphis* is probably fairly easy for a reader to recognize after a little research because of the use of *Didelphis* as a scientific name. A few languages also seem to have a common noun based on the scientific name: Polish *dydelf* and the constructed language Esperanto's *didelfo.*

One thing that makes me a little hesistant to use this, aside from its apparent artificiality as a name, is that it's not that obvious how it ought to be declined.

- Nouns ending in *-is* can have various sorts of stems; native Latin words tend to be third-declension "mixed" i-stems while words borrowed from Greek are often *-id-* stems. Concretely, this means that the accusative (which is what you would use in the context of a sentence like "Heri [opposum] vidi") would not be *didelphis,* but would probably be *didelphem* or *didelphidem.* (Technically, a "pure" i-stem form *didelphim* would also be possible, although this was a fairly rare declension pattern.)
- Since the names of biological genera are rarely declined, I can't actually tell whether there is an established consensus about the stem of *Didelphis.* Here is one source that uses ["Spiroptera Didelphidis virginianae"](https://books.google.com/books?id=R4vNAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA644&lpg=PA644&dq=%22Didelphis%22+%22virginianae%22) and another that uses "[Spiroptera Didelphis virginianae](https://books.google.com/books?id=GrZCAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA44&lpg=PA44&dq=%22Didelphis%22+%22virginianae%22)".
- Unfortunately, I can't use etymology as a guide because I can't find out whether the *-is* termination of *[Didelphis](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Didelphis)* is anything more than an arbitrary formation. Wiktionary, in saying that it is from "Ancient Greek δι- (di-, “two”) + δελφύς (delphús, “womb”)", seems to imply that it could be viewed as a variant spelling for *Didelphys,* but the inflection of that in Latin wouldn't be much simpler, since there were varying degrees of Latinization of words ending in *-ys* (e.g. the accusative of a word *didelphys* in Latin might be *didelphyn* instead of *didelphym*).