# Is the constellation named Lupus a male wolf? or could it be female?

Tags: suffixes

Unlike most constellations, Lupus isn't named after a specific character in mythology. It used to be a dog or beast, but eventually it was given the Latin name Lupus. I'm not really sure how gender suffixes work in Latin. It seems like "-us" is associated with male names. But, then again maybe in Latin, Lupus could mean a wolf of either gender, while something like Lupa would only refer to a she-wolf.

So, does the name "Lupus" imply that it is a male wolf? or could it be a female wolf?

(I'm writing a story, and was hoping to reference the constellation Lupus as a she-wolf, but I could change it to "Lupa" or something else if that would fit better. I like the name Lupus because it's the name of an actual constellation, but only if it fits.)

Comment: There is a [related question on animal gender](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/1410/79).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is in fact a word *[lupa](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dlupa)* which is the normal word for a female wolf. (If you use it in your story, however, you might want to be aware that for whatever reason, it's also a common word for "prostitute".)

As for *[lupus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dlupus1)*, as per the L&S entry, it seems normally to refer to a male wolf, though apparently there were some uses of the phrase *lupus femina* in old poets to mean *lupa*. My sense is that any readers of your story who know any Latin would be surprised to see *lupus* referring to a female wolf.

Comment: Considering that a she-wolf figures pretty prominently in the founding of Rome, and everything I can find [refers to that she-wolf as a *lupa*](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=%23Romul+~+%23lup), this definitely seems right.

Comment: I would add though that _lupus_ could certainly be used to refer to a wolf of unknown gender - You'd say _Apparently a lupus ate my chicken_, and noboy would complain if it turned out to be a female wolf.